# Apache 2 with SSL virtual host on different port 8080 or 8081 in Linux

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, ssl, ports

I was trying to configure SSL(443) for one of the virtual hosts configured in Linux with same domain name  with diffrent port number
I have used mod_ssl for the configuring the https.
For virtual hosts 80 with https it is working fine.Now the problem is 
I have configured another virtalhosts on port number 8081 and 8082 and I want to provide the HTTPS for both 8081 and 8082 configured Virtuals Hosts.

Sites with port number 8081 and 8082 are working but I need those ports has to work with https

Can anyone please help me on this

I have tried below configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:443 *8081>
    ServerName Test.domain.com
    SSLProxyEngine on
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/server.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/server.key
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/test/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443 *8082>
    ServerName Test.domain.com
    SSLProxyEngine on
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/server.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/server.key
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/test2/
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Listen 443
Listen 8081
Listen 8082

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8081>
    ServerName Test.domain.com
    SSLProxyEngine on
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/server.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/server.key
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/test/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8082>
    ServerName Test.domain.com
    SSLProxyEngine on
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/server.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/server.key
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/test2/
</VirtualHost>
```

Please refer to more examples for VirtualHost: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html